# How To Change Activity Preview/Screenshot in Recent tasks list

Tags: android

When the application is running, as Image 1. Then the menu button on the phone is pressed, it will invoke `onPause ()`, will display the image 2.

How can I change the application display as Figure 3 when `onPause ()` is called?.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the Preview on your Activity by setting

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

You can only disable the preview but you can't modify that image.